# Importing Models from Maya to OpenGL

Tags: opengl, models, maya

I am looking for ways to import models to my game project. I am using Maya as modelling software, and GLUT for windowing of my game. I found [this](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/opengl/Working-with-3D-models/) great parser, it imports all the textures and normal vectors, but it is compatible with .obj files of 3dsMAX. I tried to use it with Maya obj's, and it turned out that Maya's obj files are a bit different from former one, thus it cannot parse them.

If you know any way to convert Maya obj files to 3dsMax obj files, that would be acceptable as well as a new parser for Maya obj files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It appears that I need to triangulate my model in Maya before I export it. It is working now.

I think I am going to leave this post for future reference.